# Mutiny: Process multiple Unis and use value from "outside"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x, mutiny

I've the following method:

```
private boolean isAllProcessedForChannel(String channel) {
    KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> consumer = clientService.getConsumer(channel);

    Uni<Map<TopicPartition, Long>> positionsUni = consumer.getPositions();
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> positions = positionsUni.await().indefinitely();
    for (Entry<TopicPartition, Long> entry : positions.entrySet()) {
      Long position = entry.getValue();
      TopicPartition partition = entry.getKey();

      Uni<Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>> committedUni = consumer.committed(partition);
      OffsetAndMetadata offsetAndMetadata = committedUni.await().indefinitely().get(partition);
      if (offsetAndMetadata != null) {
        long offset = offsetAndMetadata.offset();
        log.info("Offset/Position ({}): {}/{}", partition.partition(), offset, position);
        if (offset != position) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In the end I need to get an Uni which indicates, if one of the partitions is not yet processed. My current solution is to `await` on 2 positions. I don't get how to do this whole thing "really" reactive.

For every entry in the map of the first Uni, I need to call a method which itself returns an Uni. I then need to compare a value from the entry (first Uni) with the result of the second Uni. And in the end I need to check if all the compare-results are true and return this as a single Uni.

Has anyone a hint on how to achieve this? Or is this just too complicated and I should stay with my "synchronous" way?

Comment: If the method itself does not return a Future or other async type then what is the point of doing reactive approach within the method? Is there really any benefit to doing this?

Comment: The method should return an `Uni<Boolean>` in the end, so the signature will be: `private Uni<Boolean> isAllProcessedForChannel(String channel)`. In the above code it returns a simple `boolean`, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first transform the positions entries to `Multi` then, for each entry, get a `Uni<Boolean>` which emits `false` when position is different from offset. Eventually you merge the results and take the first `false` one only:

```
private Uni<Boolean> isAllProcessedForChannel(String channel) {
    return consumer.getPositions()
            .onItem().transformToMulti(positions -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(positions.entrySet()))
            .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(entry -> {
                Long position = entry.getValue();
                TopicPartition partition = entry.getKey();

                return consumer.committed(partition).onItem().transform(committed -> {
                    OffsetAndMetadata offsetAndMetadata = committed.get(partition);
                    if (offsetAndMetadata != null) {
                        long offset = offsetAndMetadata.offset();
                        if (offset != position) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            })
            .filter(Boolean.FALSE::equals)
            .toUni();
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks a lot!